# How to get current date in certain format with PHP?

Tags: php, date, format

I want to get current date and time in certain format .
and current timestamp minus 15 minutes in certain format .

How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code :

```
echo "current time: " .date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

echo "<br>current timestamp minus 15 minutes :". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could get current datetime using php date() function, for your format you could use following code -

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

for current time stamp minus 15 minutes you could use time() function -`echo time() - (15 * 60)`

to get exact time of minus 15 minutes in datetime format you could use this code - `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - (15 * 60));`

Answer (score -1):

Current time: 
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
    $date = date('m-d-Y h:i:s a', time());

-minus 15 minutes:
    echo date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'));

Try and google next time :)